# Some overlays in Drupal not showing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Some overlays are not showing when I'm logged in to my site. The overlays that ARE working:
Dashboard, content, people ARE working, 
NOT working:
structure, appearence, module, configuration, reports

I don't know if it is the cause of the problem, but I've noticed that the overlays that are working have a URL in the form of:
http:///?q=user/1#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin%252Fcontent
while the overlays that do not work forward to a shorter form:
http:///?q=admin%2Fappearance&

I have absolutely no clue what could be the issue here, or how to investigate. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: You can disable the overlays if needed. I don't like them.

Comment: How do I disable overlays? I can't access 'the configuration menu now (since drupal tries to open it in an overlay)

Comment: `/admin/modules` will get you there. `Overlay` is just a module you can disable.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime back i was facing this issue. Not sure how i resolved it. But could you try clearing all caches once and try to access the admin pages.

Also, if you can post anything watchdog catches while accessing admin pages will be helpful in debugging.

Comment: Is there a way for me to view the watchdog logs without using the menu?  
According to drupal.org I can access watchdog logs via "view dblog report at Administration >> Reports >> Recent log messages (admin/reports/dblog).". However: clicking 'Reports' does not work ( it redirects to http://--mysite--/?q=admin%2Freports& which opens an empty page.

Comment: You should be able to view the watchdog messages at http://--site--/admin/reports/dblog